# clearValidators() used with updateValueAndValidity() does not clear errors from the control

Tags: angular, forms

Required to dynamically set the validations on the formcontrols. I am able to do this with the setValidators(). Now, when I remove the validations(once an error has been set) using the clearValidators() followed by updateValueAndValidity(), it does not remove the errors from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Errors are not cleared when validators are dynamically cleared. You need to use setErrors(null) to clear all the previous validation errors.